# Stopping a value from being updated after being defined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have it so that upon the start of a function an "oldvalue" is created that is based on the contents of a text field, since I want certain textfields to be updated automatically until edited. So the thought behind it is that I compare the oldvalue to the value currently in the textbox that is editable and if they don't match, to stop editing that field. However when I define the oldvalue based on a non-editable textbox it keeps updating when that box is changed automatically. In other words, how do I stop a value from updating after first setting it?

```
function DescChanged() {
            desc = document.getElementById("Txb_Description");
            input = document.getElementById("Txb_WebArtName");
            kortinput = document.getElementById("KortBesc");
            langinput = document.getElementById("LangBesc");
            merk = document.getElementById("Brand");
            bestelnr = document.getElementById("Txb_ArticleOrderNr");
            const inputold = input;
```

With this if clause:

```
if (kortinput.value == inputold.value || isEmptyOrSpaces(kortinput.value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having a variable outside the function, and use a temporary variable within the function, as:

```
var inputold = "";
function DescChanged() {
        desc = document.getElementById("Txb_Description");
        input = document.getElementById("Txb_WebArtName");
        kortinput = document.getElementById("KortBesc");
        langinput = document.getElementById("LangBesc");
        merk = document.getElementById("Brand");
        bestelnr = document.getElementById("Txb_ArticleOrderNr");
        // check if values are equal
        if (kortinput.value == inputold.value || isEmptyOrSpaces(kortinput.value))
            const inputold = input; // update the oldvalue
}
```

Comment: Issue with that is that before the function is called it has no value. So when the space for the textbox isn't empty, it just sees the if statement as false. Even if the textbox isn't edited manually.